# Proof verification: If $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ spans $V$ then so does $\dots$ - Axler - LADR p35

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

**Exercise:**

> Prove that If $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ spans $V$ then so does $(v_1-v_2,v_2-v_3,\dots,v_{n-1}-v_n)$ obtained by subtracting from each vector (except the last one) the following vector.

---

**My attempt:**

Since we can take the first vector in the new span, and add the next vector to it, we can obtain $(v_1 - v_2 + v_2 - v_3)$, if we do this until we reach the final vector, we obtain $(v_1-v_n)$, we can do this for every vector in the new span, giving us $(v_1 - v_n,v_2-v_n,\dots,v_{n-1}-v_n)$.

Our new apparent span is then $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1})-(v_n,\dots,v_n)$(of the same size)

This is our original spanning set, without $v_n$, but since we are taking $v_n$ from all of the vectors, $v_n$ is in this new set, hence the new set does span $V$.$\blacksquare$

---

**Question:** Does this proof work?

---

**Origin:** Axler - Linear Algebra Done Right, page 35 - - - - - - Chapter $2$ exercises - Question $1$

Answer (score 0):

You left out the $v_n$ from the question, so as you stated it, the result is false. A vector $v_n$ needs to be added to the end of the second family of vectors.

I would object to the way you word your proof - we can do this, we can do that. You don't spell out how the doing translates into actual statements about the subsets of $V$ involved. So it's hard to understand what is meant.

Let $W = \operatorname{span}(v_1 - v_2, v_2 - v_3, \dots, v_{n-1} - v_n, v_n)$. I would break the proof into two steps:

1) Check that all the vectors $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ all belong to $W$. You can do this by descending induction starting from $n$. This is how the "doing" is actually used.

2) Note that a subspace of $V$ that contains each of $v_1$, $v_2$, ..., $v_n$ must be all of $V$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will see what I can do with this in mind.